# Use parent and child blocks in a for-loop, including variables

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twig

Is there are way I can create an easily maintainable for loop in Twig that works with Bootstrap's layout?

I'm using bootstrap's row functionality, meaning that each row has a div of class "row". This makes things tricky in twig, because I have no way of entering these header divs.

For example, my main page will have several articles, and extends the skeleton template, as shown below. Is there any way I can use this skeleton base and use it multiple times in a for loop?

I've tried by adding the Article block, but it overrides everything inside. Do I have to create another template for this to work?

```
<div id="main" class="container-fluid">
    {% block article %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div id="title" class="col-md-6">
            {% block title %}
            {% endblock title %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div id="left-nav" class="col-md-2">
            {% block left_nav %}
            {% endblock left_nav %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="content">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock content %}
        </div>
        <div id="right-nav" class="col-md-2">
            {% block right_nav %}
            {% endblock right_nav %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
    {% endblock article %}
</div>
```

How do I iterate and create multiple "Articles" in this context?

Using parent() isn't helpful because it'll just print the start and end tags, wheras I need them to be placed *around* the correct sections, otherwise the rows won't work.

In other words, in a for loop context, how can I change the values of variables inside child blocks within a parent block?

Apologies if this is unclear, I found it hard to put into words.

Edit:
*I know the existence of for loops in twig, I am just unsure of how to implement a solution to this particular problem.*

As a simple example of the skeleton template and its output:

## Template

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="title">
    {% block title %}{% endblock %}
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </div>
</div>
```

## Output

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="title">
    This is the first post.
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    Post 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="title">
    This is the second post.
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    Post 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that is fairly maintainable, as it still extends the skeleton template, but is flexible enough to support for loops inside a block.

## Skeleton

```
<div id="main" class="container-fluid">
    {% block article %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div id="whitespace" class="col-md-6">
            {% block title %}
            {% endblock title %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div id="left-nav" class="col-md-2">
            {% block left_nav %}
            {% endblock left_nav %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="content">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock content %}
        </div>
        <div id="right-nav" class="col-md-2">
            {% block right_nav %}
            {% endblock right_nav %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
    {% endblock article %}
</div>
```

## Article list

```
{% extends 'skeleton.php' %}
    {% block article %}
        {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="row">
            {# Start title #}
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div id="title" class="col-md-6">
                {{post.title}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            {# End title #}
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            {# Start left-nav #}
            <div id="left-nav" class="col-md-2">
                {{post.left}}
            </div>
            {# end left-nav #}

            {# Start content #}
            <div class="col-md-6" id="content">
                {{post.getBody}}
            </div>
            {# end content #}

            {# start right-nav #}
            <div id="right-nav" class="col-md-2">
                {{post.right}}
            </div>
            {# end right-nav #}
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock article %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% foreach article in articles %}
<div class="row">
  <div class="title">
    {{ article.title }}
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    {{ article.content }}
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Is the template assuming articles is an array containing arrays with keys title and content

Comment: See edit - I am aware of what to use to fix the problem, just don't know how to use it in this case

Comment: Use article.variable to change the parts ?

Comment: Specifically speaking, I am talking about how I use the child blocks inside a for loop. For example, in that template, the extending template needs to print the article block several times and then fill in its child blocks with the actual content.

Comment: I'm not sure you can. Blocks are template level and your talking iteration level. You can probably achieve what you want using if statements